# Expectation of cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distributed random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ be a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Let $\Phi$ be the cumulative distribution function of the variable $X$. The find the expectation of $\Phi(X)$.

I have 
$$
  E(\Phi(X))=
  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x)\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\;\mathrm{d}x,
  \quad\text{where}\quad
  \Phi(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\;\mathrm{d}t.
$$ 
I am stuck here. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier approach.

Note that $\Phi(x)$ is a continuous increasing function going from $0$ to $1$. Let $Y=\Phi(X)$, so $Y$ is in the interval $(0,1)$. Then $$F(y)=\Pr(Y \le y) =\Pr(\Phi(X) \le y) = y$$ so $f(y)=1$ when $y \in (0,1)$ and $E[Y]=\int_0^1 y \,f(y) \, dy =\frac12$.

This works for any continuous distribution.

Comment: I did not understand why $\Pr(\Phi(X) \le y) = y$.

Comment: $\Phi(X)\le y$ when $X \le \Phi^{-1}(y)$, and this has probability $\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(y))$, which is $y$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer above is called the [*probability integral transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform). Aside from using that, we can directly compute the expectation with integration by parts. First, note that the pdf is the derivative of the cdf.
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\Phi\left(X\right)\right] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi\left(x\right)\phi\left(x\right)\, dx\\
&= \left.\Phi^{2}\left(x\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi\left(x\right)\phi\left(x\right) \, dx\\
&= 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi\left(x\right)\phi\left(x\right) \, dx \qquad \left(=1-\mathbb{E}\left[\Phi\left(X\right)\right] \right)\\
2\mathbb{E}\left[\Phi\left(X\right)\right] &= 1
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\Phi\left(X\right)\right] = 1/2
$$