# Expectation of normal c.d.f. of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $a$ be a constant, X is a standard normal and $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of standard normal.

1. what is the $$E[\Phi(aX)]$$
2. what is the $$E[\Phi(X + a])]$$

my approach would be to derive the density of $g(X) = Y = aX$ and of $g(X)=Y=X+a$ (which should result in $1/a$ and $1$, respectively. Please let me know if this sounds correct.)

Is there a faster way? I found the below answer but do not take into account the role of the constant. Once we have a constant we can't cancel out the two c.d.f.

In my approach i get to $$\Phi\large(g^{-1}(x)\large)$$ and then using chain rule to arrive to the density. Results that i get doing this are indeed  $1/a$ and $1$.

[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331093/expectation-of-cumulative-distribution-function-of-a-standard-normal-distributed#:~:text=Let%20X%20be%20a%20normally,√2πdt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331093/expectation-of-cumulative-distribution-function-of-a-standard-normal-distributed#:%7E:text=Let%20X%20be%20a%20normally,%E2%88%9A2%CF%80dt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way:

By writing down the integral you can notice that
$$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)] = P(Y \leq Z + a)$$
where $Y, Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ are independent. Then $Y-Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ so
$$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)] = P(Y - Z \leq a) = \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

The case of $\mathbb{E}[aX]$ is even easier! As before, notice that
$$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX)] = P\left(Y \leq aZ\right)$$
with $Y,Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ independent. But $Y-aZ \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1+a^2)$ and from there you get
$$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX)] = P(Y-aZ \leq 0) = \Phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$$

**EDIT:** Here is a more detailed calculation:

Let $\phi(x)$ be the CDF of a standard normal RV. Then [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) tells us that
$$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x+a)\phi(x)dx$$
By definition,
$$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$$
so
$$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{x+a}\phi(t)\phi(x)\,dtdx$$
which is exactly what you would get if you were to calculate the probability $P(Y\leq Z+a)$ (up to renaming of the dummy integration variables).

Comment: It looks like the density that I got for the change of variable Y are wrong! Can you elaborate on $E[\Phi(X+a)]=P(Y<Z+a)$? I don’t see it

Comment: @Buddy_ I have edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the second case, namely $Y = g(X) = \Phi(X+a)$. You may indeed determine the new density function from the usual change of variable, so that
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\partial g^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}\right|,
$$
where the last factor is nothing else than the Jacobian resulting from the chain rule. In the present case, computations promise to be tedious because of the form of $g$.

Instead, if I were you, I would "cheat" by trying to produce a differential equation with respect to the parameter $a$, as done below :
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)] 
   &= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\Phi(X+a)\right] \\
   &= \mathbb{E}[\phi(X+a)] \\
   &= \int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x)\phi(x+a) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x+a)^2} \\
   &= \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+ax+\frac{a^2}{2})} \\
   &= \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}a^2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}} 
\end{align}
$$
hence, after integration (by separation of the variables),
$$
\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)] = \int_{-\infty}^a \frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{2\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{4}\alpha^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{a/\sqrt{2}} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2} = \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right),
$$
where we used the boundary condition $\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X+a)]|_{a=-\infty} = 0$, since $\Phi(-\infty) = 0$.

Of course, you may proceed in the same way with the first case, i.e. $Y = \Phi(aX)$. You will end up with the following expression :
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX)] = \mathbb{E}[X\phi(aX)] = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} x\phi(x)\phi(ax) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{2\pi} xe^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+a^2)x^2} = 0,
$$
because the integrand is odd. In consequence, $\mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX)]$ is constant with respect to the parameter $a$, hence
$$
\mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX)] = \mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX)]|_{a=0} = \mathbb{E}[\Phi(0)] = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: This is not correct since for $a=1$ it is well known that $E[\Phi(X)]=1/2$ whereas your formula suggests it is equal to $(\sqrt{2}-1)/\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis is right. Note that $\partial_a\Bbb E[\Phi(aX)]=\Bbb E[X\Phi'(aX)]\ne\Bbb E[a\Phi'(aX)]$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis   You're right, I went a bit too quickly in my derivation. Now it is corrected.

Comment: @J.G.   You're right, I went a bit too quickly in my derivation. Now it is corrected.

Comment: thank you @Abezhiko, this is also brilliant! I added another question linked to this question, you might want to get a look if interested https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820629/density-of-normal-c-d-f-of-a-normal-random-variable