# Density of normal c.d.f. of a normal random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, density-function

Let $a$ be a constant, X is a standard normal and $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of standard normal.

1. what is the density of $Y$ where $$Y = \Phi(aX)$$
2. what is the density of $$Y=\Phi(X + a)$$

The second case seems to me that doesn't have a clean density, if so, we can skip this part as it will not be too helpful.
For the first case, defining as $\phi(x)$ the density of a standard normal, in my approach i get to $$\phi\Large(\small\frac{\Phi^{-1}(x)}{a}\Large)\small \frac{1}{a\phi(\Phi^{-1}(x))} $$ but then i'm not sure how to proceed. Considering  $\Phi^{-1}(x) = y$ as is the same function inside the two density i get $$\frac{1}{a}\large e^{\small-\frac{y^2}{2\frac{a^2}{1-a^2}}}$$but this form doesn't look too good.  The final purpose is to then compute
$$E[\Phi(aX)]$$
which i know to be equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. See [Expectation of normal c.d.f. of a normal random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810116/expectation-of-normal-c-d-f-of-a-normal-random-variable)